Pades versioning - how to retrieve original version of a PDF signed with pades
I am trying to understand how pades certificates work. I know pades allow versioning of a file. The question is how can I retrieve the original pdf having the signed version? Is there a way to do so?
Thanks
I tried to open the file on Adobe Reader and look into the certificate for some information but couldn't find any field referring to previous versions.
